# Javascript how to confirm browser close in Safari on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios

Is there a way in javascript to show a confirmation alert and give the user an opportunity to cancel before closing browser/tab in mobile safari? Since onbeforeunload is not supported I'm wondering if there's another way to interrupt the process?

Comment: It's October 2017 and here I am looking for an answer to this, and nothing seems to work. Thanks to Apple and their disregard/contempt for standards.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at Apple's Documentation?

https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW5

`document.unload` should work but is deprecated.  `document.pagehide` is recommended.

Comment: I should have been more clear. I need to let the user cancel the close. pagehide does not seem to allow this.

Comment: Question updated for clarity. Thumbs up though for good info given the original phrasing of the question.